# how to close port 135 from win2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewall

how to close port 135 from win2003 server

It seems Windows firewall opens it always itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a required port for microsoft network services.  You should block it at your firewall and not let the interwebs in, but if you want to block 135 on the server itself, you're gonna have issues.

http://www.iss.net/security_center/advice/Exploits/Ports/groups/Microsoft/default.htm

If you really want to block it, stopping the workstation and server services, and removing the "Client for Microsoft Networks" from the network interface in question should do the trick - although I've never really tried to function without all three.

You will pretty muich kill your ability to access shares, share data yourself, or really participate at all on a domain.

At that point, you might as well install linux - it's cheaper.  :)